# Magento 2 how to add date of birth in checkout (date picker)

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, html, guest-checkout, datepicker

I want to add the date of birth date picker in checkout only for guest users.
I have read a few things which indicate that I have to use knockoutjs.
But I wasn’t sure what is the correct way to approach this.
Is there anything I could follow as in guideline or any help I could use